# Restore diacritics in utf8 format - Linux

Tags: utf-8, text-files, restore, diacritics

I've got several text files full of sentences like this: "Mais, tu n'as pas fait tes devoirs ?!" -\u00c9l\u00e8ve : "Ben non"

Is there a quick way (script or utility) to restore all the diacritics in utf8 format? (expected result: Élève : "Ben non")

I could do it manually with sed but since my text files contain diacritics peculiar to several languages, that would take too much time.

Thank you very much

Comment: What (scripting) languages do have access to/feel comfortable with?

Comment: Shell script, that's about it.. i am a complete newbie. Thats why i was wondering whether there was a readymade solution to tell you the truth

Comment: Find a stand-alone French spell-check library?

Comment: If it were only one language, I would have used sed with a list of predefined of replacements. What I'm trying to do is to find a script or utility that would convert every possible unicode conversion, or at least, those present at:  [link](http://lexicon.ff.cuni.cz/about/aa_character_encoding.html)

Comment: Alright, I found something.`python -c "print  u'\u00e9lev\n'.encode('utf8')"` does work. But how do I apply this to a whole file?

Answer (score 1):

I found it...

```
python -c "print (open('filetoconvert.txt','rb').read().decode('unicode-escape').encode('utf-8'))"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Java JDK installed, there's a utility program called `native2ascii` for converting files to and from unicode escapes. For example:

```
native2ascii -reverse filetoconvert.txt > converted.txt
```